# Fubini´s Application

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I don't think this should be difficult, but I can't prove this equality. I need to show that 
$$
  \int\limits_0^a\int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^y f(z)
    \;\mathrm{d}z\;\mathrm{d}y\;\mathrm{d}x
    = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{a}f(z)(z-a)^2dz
$$ 
By Fubini's Theorem I got this two equalities 
$$
  \int\limits_0^a\int\limits_0^y\int\limits_0^x f(z) 
    \;\mathrm{d}x\;\mathrm{d}z\;\mathrm{d}y
    = \int\limits_0^y f(z)\frac{a^2}{2} \;\mathrm{d}z
  \\ \text{and} \\ 
  \int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^y\int\limits_0^a f(z) 
    \;\mathrm{d}x\;\mathrm{d}z\;\mathrm{d}y
    = \int\limits_0^y f(z) ax \;\mathrm{d}z
$$ 
This looks a little like the result except that I don't got $\int_{0}^{a}$ and I should got another equality, does anybody have a hint?